# MongoDB cache collection in memory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, caching, geospatial

I am using `mongoDB` to store a collection of polygons and use `$geoIntersects` queries to find in which polygon a specific point is.

My `mongoose` `Schema` looks like this:

```
var LocationShema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    geo: {
        type: {
            type: String 
        },
        coordinates: []
    }
});

LocationShema.index({geo: '2dsphere'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Location', LocationShema);
```

So, each element is a polygon. I added the `2dsphere` index hoping that the queries would be faster and the entire collection would be stored in memory. Unfortunately it takes about `600ms` for ~20queries which is way too much for my use case.

My queries look like this:

```
Location.find({
            geo: {
                $geoIntersects: {
                    $geometry: {
                        type: 'Point',
                        coordinates: [pos.lng, pos.lat]
                    }
                }
            }
 },...)
```

Is there anyway I can make this run faster? Can I force MongoDB to cache the entire collection in the database (as ther collection never changes). Is there any way I can **check if the collection is actually stored in an in-memory cache**?

Also, are there any alternatives I can use (eg: a library or something) that allows for fast geo-spatial queries?

Comment: Can you post a `explain()` of your query?

Comment: when executing a query in mongo shell use 'db.collectionName.find(query).explain()'

Comment: Hmm, but I'm using `mongoose` and not using the shell, I will try that, thanks.

Comment: Here is the explain: http://codepaste.net/qjaron

Comment: How exactly are you running those 20 queries? Concurrently, sequentially? Can they be folded into a single query perhaps?

Comment: I query sequentially, in a for loop, a query for each of the 20 points. How can I group them? I need to find for each point it's polygon.

Comment: Try running them concurrently.

Comment: @robertklep I mean, the queries run all at the same time, not waiting one for another (I meant that the calls are sequentially, made one after another, but the queries themselves may be concurrent), but I do have 20 `Location.find()` calls happening. Can I somehow batch all the 20 queries in a single call?

Comment: @Cristy yes, that would be concurrent. Not sure if you can run them in a single query; you could use an elaborate `$or` query but I don't know if you would be able to easily track which result would match which of the 20 points.

Comment: @robertklep As for now, I managed to reduce the time from 600ms to 150ms by linear-searching through all polygons for each point (so without any MongoDB geospatial query). I think the linear search will always be faster than querying as long as the number of polygons is under 200 or so (atm there are 100 polygons).

Answer (score 2):

With mongo >3.0 you can use inMemory storage, so that means you could have instance of mongo when seeded collection stays in memory (all changes aren't persisted).

From other side if your collection is static - there could be a way to implement a cache storage like Redis, or even TTL indexed collection with stored query and response.

the process of seeding could be done by backup of current collection and restore in in memory collection.

When querying frequently collection - it residues in memory as long as mongo needs to load other collections (on  busy system).

Any comments welcome!

Comment: So, can I use `inMemory` storage just for this collection? How do I "seed" the collection?

Comment: I would expect that after running the queries once the relevant disk blocks are present in the OS's disk buffers (provided that there is enough memory available).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot keep a specific collection into memory but the others into disk, but bear in mind that mongodb internally is doing some caching when you execute the same query again and again.

What you can do it the following:

- Option 1: You can create a "view" with `$merge` or `$out` and query this collection with a find (all). BTW some times it's better to do a full scan instead of going by indexes (in case you have many results especially if each document is big in size). So with the "view" you can go without any index - since you do a find all - and you have better changes your results to be cached. This also related how big is you RAM since maybe mongodb needs to swap data in RAM
- Option 2: If your data are read-only you can load a mongodb completenly in-memory (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/inmemory/) having only this collection. But you have to find a way when the mongodb restarted to create and populate again the collection.